# I keep getting a Persistent ValueError: too many values to unpack and i don't understand why

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am getting this error and i think i have spent 5 hours on it. Please someone help.
I eventually want to get the values out of this.
What is causing there to be many values? Is it my string values or the setup of the dictionary itself.

```
import ast
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
class MyMetric:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

        self.metric_system = {
                         "yotta":  ("Y", str(10^24) ),
                         "zetta":  ("Z", str(10^21)),
                         "exa":    ("E", str(10^18)),
                         "peta":   ("P", str(10^15)),
                         "tera":   ("T", str(10^12)),
                         "giga":   ("G", str(10^9)),
                         "mega":   ("M", str(10^6)),
                         "kilo":   ("k", str(10^3)),
                         "hecto":  ("h", str(10^2)),
                         "deka":   ("da", str(10^1)),
                         "deci":   ("d", str(10^-1)),
                         "centi":  ("c", str(10^-2)),
                         "milli":  ("m",  str(10^-3)),
                         "micro":  ("μ", str(10^-6)),
                         "nano":   ("n", str(10^-9)), 
                         "pico":   ("p", str(10^-12)),
                         "femto":  ("f", str(10^-15)),
                         "atto":   ("a", str(10^-18)),
                         "zepto":  ("z", str(10^-21)),
                         "yocto":  ("y", str(10^-24))   
                         } 

    def __str__(self): 
        for key,val in self.metric_system:

            self.metric_name = key
            self.metric_symbol = val[0]
            self.metric_value = val[1]

            if self.name == self.metric_name:
                print  ("it is there")



me =  MyMetric("milli")  
print(me)
```

Comment: `for key,val in self.metric_system` -> `for key,val in self.metric_system.items()`

Comment: `^` is not the `power-of` operator, it is the bitwise `XOR` operator. `2^5 = 7` because `0010 XOR 0101 = 0111`. The correct operator is `**`. `2 ** 5 = 32`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looping over a dictionary gives you *only the keys*. Use the [`dict.items()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items) when you want both the key and the value:

```
for key, val in self.metric_system.items():
```

From the [`dict()` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict):

> `iter(d)`
>   Return an iterator over the keys of the dictionary. This is a shortcut for `iter(d.keys())`.

A `for` loop uses `iter()` on the item being looped over, internally.

Note that the `__str__` method is expected to **return** a string, not print it.

However, there is little point in iterating over all values in the dictionary when you *already have the key*. You can simply do:

```
def __str__(self): 
    if self.name in self.metric_system:
        return "it is here"
    return "it is not here"
```

or use dictionary lookup to get the values:

```
def __str__(self): 
    try:
        symbol, magnitude = self.metric_system[self.name]
    except KeyError:
        return 'Unknown metric {}'.format(self.name)
    return 'Metric {} ({}, {})'.format(self.name, symbol, magnitude)
```

Demo:

```
>>> print(MyMetric("milli"))
Metric milli (m, -9)
>>> print(MyMetric("foobar"))
Unknown metric foobar
```

Answer (score 0):

Your loop should be

```
for key,val in self.metric_system.items():
```

This will iterate over pairs of `(key, value)`